# How does one get properties from related table as properties of it's own table in Laravel 5?

Tags: database, laravel, relational-database, laravel-5

The question might sound a little bit confusing but I don't know how to explain it better in one sentence.

This describes basically what the problem is:

I have a Users table which can contain 2 types of users. I know how I can separate by role. But here's the thing, users with role 1(editor_in_chief) have different attributes than users with role 2(reviewer).

My idea was to create a table named 'reviewer_attributes' and 'editor_in_chief_attributes' and create a one-to-one relation with this table to hold the attributes for the users table.

Maybe you have a better idea, that would be great as well. But for this scenario, I would like to know if it is possible to make a call to the database and to get these users' properties from the other table as properties of the User object.

When using a DB call using relations laravel will give me something like this:

```
user {
   id: 1,
   name: "Name",
   reviewer_attributes: {
      attribute_1: 'attribute_1',
      attribute_2: 'attribute_2',
      attribute_3: 'attribute_3',
   }
}
```

But this is what I want to object to obtain look like:

```
user {
   id: 1,
   name: "Name",
   attribute_1: 'attribute_1',
   attribute_2: 'attribute_2',
   attribute_3: 'attribute_3',
}
```

I want to achieve this by a single database call instead of setting the properties after the call.

I find this a very interesting topic, I hope you could help!

Comment: What is your DB call that gives you that result?

Comment: @Hafez When obtaining data like this  User::with('reviewerAttributes')->find($id);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your problem right, you may call somthing like this:

```
DB::table('users')
    ->join('reviewer_attributes', 'users.id', '=', 'reviewer_attributes.user_id')
    ->find($id);
```

you may add `select` to get specific attributes of each table:

```
DB::table('users')
    ->join('reviewer_attributes', 'users.id', '=', 'reviewer_attributes.user_id')
    ->select('users.id', 'users.name', 'reviewer_attributes.*')
    ->find($id);
```

**Update**: You can also use [collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-collections) to restructure your results returned by Eloquent:

```
$result = User::with('reviewerAttributes')->find($id);

$result = $result->get('reviewer_attributes')
                 ->merge($result->forget('reviewer_attributes')->all())
                 ->all();
```

Comment: Thank you, this works indeed! Do you also know how I can get this done using the relationship methods of Laravel. Like when you call User::with('reviewerAttributes')->find($id); ?

Comment: @TheBurgerShot You can't get the result structure you want by using the relationship methods because it returns `user->reviewer_attributes->attribute_1` instead of `user->attribute_1`. Why do you insist on using relationships?

Comment: Because when I want to get the user object with the reviewer_attributes as a relation of another object, I can easily do this with just one call. For example: 
Publication::with('user.reviewerAttributes')->find($id);
But your answer is perfectly fine, I was just wondering if it could be done even cleaner.

Comment: @TheBurgerShot I updated my answer but I didn't test it, Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: @Hafaz
Unfortunately it is not working, I get the following error:

      Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::columnize() 
must be of the type array, string given

This applies to the line '$result->get('reviewer_attributes')

I tried to change it to (array) $result->reviewerAttributes, but then I get :

strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: @TheBurgerShot I had forgotten to add `all()`, use my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need export model to Json?
If so, override `toArray` method

```
public function toArray()
{
    $arr = parent::toArray();
    $reviewer_attributes = $this->getReviewerAttributesSomeHow();
    return array_merge($arr, $reviewer_attributes);
}
```

Comment: I want to achieve this by a single query. Like when you do something like this: User::with('reviewer_attributes')->find();
But then in such a way that it processes the properties from the 'reviewer_attributes' as properties of User.