# how to combine 2 columns from different tables into 1 column in 1 table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to combine the number column and the unit column (the unit column is in the unit table). Here's my code:

```
@foreach ($item as $row)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $row->amount }}</td>
    <td>{{ $row->unit->unit }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

and this is the controller

```
$reports = loan_reports::with('unit')
            ->get();
```

Please, what should i do?

Comment: Is number column in unit table or some other table? I'm not sure so I can't write an answer because I don't know should one use JOIN or just simple SELECT.... Anyway, write SQL query and execute it using DB::select("your SELECT query"). Bare in mind, eloquent ORM is there to simplify common tasks regarding DB communication but for anything more serious, raw SQL is the right way to go from point of flexibility and performance.

Comment: What issue you are facing now?

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions for this includes "using join", "using collections", "using API resources" and "define an accessor".

To define a custom accessor, add `getUnitAttribute` to your `loan_reports` model:

```php
class loan_reportsextends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the report's unit.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUnitAttribute()
    {
        return $this->relationLoaded('unit') ? $this->unit->unit : null;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```php
@foreach ($item as $row)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $row->amount }}</td>
    <td>{{ $row->unit }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

I have explained other solutions on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37489962/3477084